# Named and Optional Parameters work in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I created a console project in Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 2.0 selected

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    public int Add(int a, int b = 0, int c = 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("a is " + a);
      Console.WriteLine("b is " + b);
      Console.WriteLine("c is " + c);
      return a + b + c;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
      Program o = new Program();
      Console.WriteLine(o.Add(10));
      Console.WriteLine(o.Add(10, 10));
      Console.WriteLine(o.Add(10, 10, 10));
      Console.WriteLine(o.Add(b: 20, a: 10));
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

It works successfully.

However the same code if I type in Visual Studio 2008, it fails!.

Could anyone please help me with this issue as Named and Optional Parameters came with C#4 ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it may be just compilation thing. Code created is completely compatible with `.NET 2.0` runtime. And VS2008 do not understand this construct since it does not understand latest `C#` specification (unless you install additional packages)

Comment: I am trying to find the exact reasons as I tried working with Covariance and Contravariance in generic interface and delegates and it works only in .NET 4.0. Other C# 4.0 features fail in .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5.

Comment: @PrakashBhatia I've addressed covariance / contravariance in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DaveShaw has explained named/optional parameters. You also mention (comments) contravariance and covariance - they are different: covariance and contravariance requires *both* compiler changes *and* library changes - `IEnumerable<T>` became `IEnumerable<out T>`, etc. That is why they don't work on older .NET versions even with new compilers.

So basically:

- if the feature you want is implemented entirely in the compiler, it will probably work on older .NET versions as long as you use a newer compiler
- if the feature you want requires BCL changes, it will probably only work on later .NET versions

  - unless that feature can actually be implemented entirely by *additional* libraries - in particular via extension methods. As an example, LINQ-to-Objects can work on older .NET versions (with newer C# versions) by adding [LINQBridge](https://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/); similarly, `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` adds types to some pre-4.5 frameworks allowing `async`/`await` to be used

Answer (score 7):

This is because Named Parameters are a feature of the C# language, not the .net runtime.

Your VS2010 uses the C# 4.0 compiler, VS2008 uses C# 3.0.

This means you can use newer features of the *language* against an older runtime library.

You can even use Linq (lamda syntax) in .Net 2.0 and VS 2010 if you implement the Linq methods your self (see the [Linq Bridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) project - this post also has a more indepth discussion as to how it all works).

Comment: I also tried other C# 4.0 features and they fail when I select .NET framework 2.0 in VS 2010

Comment: Which features are those? I work daily against .Net 2.0 with C# 4 and use all the features as far as I know. The only limitation are ones that depend on the .Net Framework (such as Linq).

Comment: @PrakashBhatia it will depend on the exact feature; i.e. does that feature depend on the compiler? the framework? or just method signatures (commonly via extension methods)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing .NET versions and C# versions.  If you compile using Visual Studio 2010, you are using the C#4 compiler.  That's regardless of the version of the .NET framework you're referencing.

The feature you're using is tied to the *compiler* version not the *framework* version, and so your code fails to compile in VS2008 (and will succeed in VS2010 regardless of target framework version).